# I'm trying to implement Pivot SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, pivot

this is my first time trying to do a pivot but even with all the information online, i'm still useless :(

I have this table.

```
+-----+-----------------+------------+
| ID  | ChecklistItemID | Attachment |
| 327 | 912             | 611        |
| 328 | 912             | 612        |
+-----+-----------------+------------+
```

and this table

```
+-----+----------+
| ID  | FileName |
| 611 | 2.jpg    |
| 612 | 3.jpg    |
+-----+----------+
```

I want my output to be like this

```
+-----------------+-------+-------+
| ChecklistItemID | File1 | File2 |
| 912             | 2.jpg | 3.jpg |
+-----------------+-------+-------+
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: What's the "input" for your query? E.g. are you trying to do this for all of your data, or are you provided with e.g. a specific ChecklistItemID or list of `ID`s, etc. Also, is there a limit to how many files may be involved?

Comment: I think your sample data has a problem.  `ChecklistItemID` `12` is only connected to one of the two attachments.

Comment: oops sorry, i've edited it.

Comment: There is a maximum of 3 rows per ChecklistItemID. ID is auto-incremental. A maximum of 3 files are involved. might be 3 or lesser

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick. I've left it quite open since you haven't said whether you're doing this for all of your data or just a specific checklist.

The trick was to use a `ROW_NUMBER()` to obtain known names for the `File` columns:

```
declare @t1 table (ID int not null,ChecklistItemID int not null,Attachment int not null)
insert into @t1(ID,ChecklistItemID,Attachment) values
(327,912,611),
(328,912,612)

declare @t2 table (ID int not null, FileName varchar(9) not null)
insert into @t2(ID,FileName) values
(611,'2.jpg'),
(612,'3.jpg')

;With Ordered as (
    select
        t1.ChecklistItemID,
        FileName,
        'File' + CONVERT(varchar(5),ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.ChecklistItemID
                                     ORDER BY t2.ID)) as FileTitle
    from
        @t1 t1
            inner join
        @t2 t2
            on
                t1.Attachment = t2.ID
)
select
    *
from
    Ordered
        pivot (MIN(FileName) for FileTitle in (File1,File2,File3)) u
```

Result:

```
ChecklistItemID File1     File2     File3
--------------- --------- --------- ---------
912             2.jpg     3.jpg     NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL
Drop table #Temp

Declare @Tab1 TABLE ( ID INT, ChecklistItemID INT , Attachment INT)
Insert into @Tab1
SELECT 327 , 912, 611 UNION ALL        
SELECT 328 , 912, 612        

Declare @Tab2 TABLE (ID INT,FileName Varchar(10))
INSERT INTO @Tab2
SELECT  611 , '2.jpg' Union all
SELECT  612 , '3.jpg'    

SELECT ChecklistItemID,[FileName] INTO #Temp FROM @Tab1 t1
INNER JOIN @Tab2 t2
ON t1.Attachment=t2.ID


DECLARE @COulmn nvarchar(max),
        @query nvarchar(max)
SELECT @COulmn= STUFF((SELECT ', '+'File'+CAST( ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY ChecklistItemID ORDER BY ChecklistItemID) AS Varchar(5))
FROM #Temp For XML PATH ('')),1,1,'') 


SET @query = N'SELECT ChecklistItemID,' + @COulmn + N' from 
             (
                SELECT *,''File''+ CAST(ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY ChecklistItemID ORDER BY ChecklistItemID) AS Varchar(5)) As FileColumn
                FROM #Temp
            ) Src
            PIVOT 
            (
                MAX([FileName])
                FOR FileColumn in (' + @COulmn + N')
            ) pvt '

EXEC sp_executesql @query;
```

OutPut

```
ChecklistItemID File1   File2
-----------------------------
912             2.jpg   3.jpg
```